# Checking validation of VTextField

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a CodePen demonstrating the issue at [Checking validation of VTextField](https://codepen.io/james-hudson3010/pen/yLOZEgz). The CodePen code is below as well.

Inside of the `updateTitle` method, I would like to be able to check to see whether or not the value is valid, because I need to run some custom logic when the value changes and what is executed will depend upon whether or not the value is valid.

I can see that v-text-field has a `valid` and `validationState` property. Is it possible to access either property inside of `updateTitle`?

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-form>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
  
          <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
            <v-text-field
              :value = "title"
              :rules="[rules.required, rules.counter]"
              label="Title"
              counter
              maxlength="20"
              @input="updateTitle"              
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
  
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      title: 'Preliminary report',
      rules: {
        required: value => !!value || 'Required.',
        counter: value => value.length <= 10 || 'Max 10 characters'
      }
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    updateTitle( value ) {
      console.log( "update", value );
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to provide a `ref` to the `v-text-field`. This allows one to access the field via the special `$refs` property and call the `validate` function. The changes to the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/james-hudson3010/pen/LYNqroP) are:

```
            <v-text-field
              ref = "theField"
              :value = "title"
              :rules="[rules.required, rules.counter]"
              label="Title"
              counter
              maxlength="20"
              @input="updateTitle"           
            ></v-text-field>
```

```
    updateTitle( value ) {
      const isValid = this.$refs.theField.validate();
      
      console.log( "update", value, isValid );
    }
```